# Why function call takes so much time?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance

I have the following insertion sort algorithm implementation:

```
private static void InsertionSort(List<int> array)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < array.Count; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && array[j - 1] > array[j]; --j)
        {
             //swap(array, j, j-1);

             int temp = array[j];
             array[j] = array[j-1];
             array[j-1] = temp;
        }
     }
}

private static void swap(List<int> array, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

When I run my algorithm with `swap(array, j, j-1);` it takes much more time (+2 seconds for 50000 elements) than if I do function body inline.

Why?

Comment: I assume that is release build? (Relevant links: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15713910/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/473782/11683)

Comment: Don't you need to say "ref" on the array argument to "swap"?

Comment: I think no. This is C#

Comment: How are you measuring times? post all code.
Also check this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization

Comment: I use Stopwatch for two algorithms. That's it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It isn't wrong to inline the method by hand, it just isn't necessary.  Inlining small methods is one of the [standard optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4045073/17034) performed by the jitter.  That doesn't always happen, but on .NET 4.6.1 both the x86 and the x64 jitters *do* inline swap() in this sample code.  And more, they also unroll the inner loop to produce *two* swaps per pass, the kind of hand-optimization programmers usually skip.

Properly benchmarking a .NET app isn't always that straight-forward.  *Very* important to run the Release build of your program.  And to *not* use the debugger.  Albeit the latter is easy to fix, use Tools > Options > Debugging > General > untick the "Suppress JIT optimization" option.  There is no good reason to turn it back on.

You can now also see the generated machine code, set a breakpoint on InsertionSort() and when it hits use Debug > Windows > Disassembly.  Tends to make people's eyes bleed but it is quite easy to see that you get two inlined swaps().  I'll spare you the assembly dump, just have a look-see.  And you should clearly see the difference in the measurement.  Here's what I get:

Running it 5 times with swap() on a List with 50,000 random integers on x64:

```
00:00:05.4447216
00:00:05.2928558
00:00:05.6960587
00:00:05.2835343
00:00:05.2809591
```

Same test but now swap() inlined by hand:

```
00:00:05.3015856
00:00:05.2877402
00:00:05.6369775
00:00:05.2603384
00:00:05.2616389
```

Takes just as long, as it should.

I would be remiss to not show the results I get with List.Sort():

```
00:00:00.0075878
00:00:00.0073398
00:00:00.0076528
00:00:00.0078046
00:00:00.0066319
```

Comment: Oh, I run Debug build of my program! What is the difference?

Comment: List.Sort(). what type of sorting algorithm it use?quick sort?

Comment: Well, you now know what the difference is, those optimizations I linked to are not performed so you do see the cost of the method call.  It uses [introspection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).

Comment: Why does it unroll the loop to do exactly *two* swaps per pass?

Comment: Exactly how many copies you get of the loop's inner body varies. Most I've ever seen is 4, swap() is a bit beefy in machine code so 2 seems a reasonable choice